# How to use multiple separate formulas in a single "IF" in Excel?

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have a basic understanding of excel formulas work and have used this site many times to broaden my knowledge, however, I'm stuck on the below and I'm hoping someone can assist me.

I'm trying to create a formula to work out if a KPI has been met. I have 3 separate formulas that I need to combine into one.

```
=IF(AND(E2="1",S2>0.041667),"YES","NO")
=IF(AND(E2="2",S2>0.125),"YES","NO")
=IF(AND(E2="3",S2>0.25),"YES","NO")
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to use an `OR` to combine them. See below:

```
=IF(OR(AND(E2="1",S2>0.041667), AND(E2="2",S2>0.125), AND(E2="3",S2>0.25)) ,"YES","NO")
```

The `OR` requires at least one argument to be true, so the statement will evaluate to `TRUE` if at least one of the the `AND` statements returns true.

Comment: Thanks Brandon. It all seems so simple now, that has worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

A bit simplified with the [`CHOOSE` function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/choose-function-fc5c184f-cb62-4ec7-a46e-38653b98f5bc) (results in `#VALUE!` error if `E2` is not 1, 2, or 3) :

```
=IF(S2 > CHOOSE(E2, 0.041667, 0.125, 0.25), "YES", "NO")
```

Comment: Worth noting in your answer that choose requires `E2` to be an index number. Agreed that this would simplify things in the event that an index number is used, but it would be less useful in the case of categories (e.g 'Tier One', 'Tier Two')

Comment: @BrandonBarney works with index text too ("1", "2", "3"). [SWITCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/switch-function-47ab33c0-28ce-4530-8a45-d532ec4aa25e) for other cases.